# How do I set up Array/List dependencies in code with Castle Windsor?

Tags: dependency-injection, castle-windsor, castle

I have the following classes:

```
class Repository : IRepository
class ReadOnlyRepository : Repository

abstract class Command
abstract CommandImpl : Command
{
     public CommandImpl(Repository repository){}
}

class Service
{
    public Service (Command[] commands){}
}
```

I register them in code as follows:

```
var container = new Container("WindsorCOntainer.config");
var container = new WindsorContainer(new XmlInterpreter("WindsorConfig.xml"));
container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new ArrayResolver(container.Kernel));
container.AddComponent("repository", typeof(RentServiceRepository));
container.Resolve<RentServiceRepository>();
container.AddComponent("command", typeof(COmmandImpl));
container.AddComponent("rentService", typeof (RentService));
container.Resolve<RentService>(); // Fails here
```

I get the message that "RentService is waiting for dependency commands"

**What am I doing wrong?**

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not registering `CommandImpl` as `Command`, you're registering it as `CommandImpl`.

if you do:

```
container.Register(Component.For<Command>().ImplementedBy<CommandImpl>());
```

it'll work.

I suggest you familiarize yourself with [the documentation](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.MainPage.ashx), especially [installers](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Installers.ashx) and [registration API](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Fluent-Registration-API.ashx)